# how to call BroadcastReceiver to Activity

Tags: android, sms

Hi my requirement is receive sms from particular number.i want to show the received  message in textview.but i unable to take the value from BroadcastReceiver in my activity  .   i do not know where i made mistake.please tell me

my code is

SmsReceiver

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public String str=null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if (bundle != null) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) 
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            //for get sms from special number===============================
            String msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            Log.v("msg_from >>",msg_from);     
            if(msg_from.equals("XXXXXXXX"))
            {
                //===============================
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";    
            Intent act = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            act.putExtra("message", str);
            context.startActivity(act);

            this.abortBroadcast();
            }

        }
        // ---display the new SMS message---
        // Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
 }
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView showText;
private String receivedSms;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    receivedSms =intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.e("mysms", receivedSms);
    showText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showText);
    showText.setText(receivedSms);
}   

  }
```

Comment: what is happening any error??

Comment: nullpointerException accrued when Log.e() message printed,if i removed Log.e it does not show any value from textview

Comment: receivedSms is null??

Comment: yes recevedSms is null

Comment: log the msg inside onReceive

Comment: ya i wrote inside onReceive it doesnt show any message

Comment: you mean it's not getting called?? check if you have declared your receiver inside manifest

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest file :

> ```
> <uses-permission
> android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
> <uses-permission
> android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
>
> <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">   
>    <intent-filter>
>      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
>    </intent-filter>  </receiver>
> ```

// inside your receiver class

> final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();   try {
>
> ```
> if (bundle != null) {
>
>     final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
>
>         SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
>         String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
>
>         String senderNum = phoneNumber;
>         String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
>
>     }
>   }   
> } 
> catch (Exception e) {
> e.printstacktrac(); 
> }
> ```
>
> pass message string to your activity.

Comment: then compare your specific number with received number.

Comment: i wrote same code what u posted but in logcat Log.e("CHEKING", message); no message printed

Comment: As per my suggestion don't use broadcast receiver to receive  messages in your app.

Comment: try to use ContentObserver to get new message

Comment: B'coz in higher api level (e.g. from  api 11) b'receiver will not call on new message receive.

Comment: k but i pass that String values from b'receiver to my main activty it does not pass any value

Comment: b'coz SmsMessage is deprecated, so its methods will not return anything else.

Comment: please tell me any solution from this

Comment: have u heard about Content Observer in android ?

Comment: No i dont know about Content Observer

Comment: then search for it on Google and if not found anything then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
public String str=null;
```

to:

```
public String str="";
```

I would suggest using StringBuffer instead and append string into it.